# How can I get recipients ID after a Facebook game request on Android (Facebook SDK v4)?

Tags: facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

On Facebook SDK v4 the GameRequestDialog.Result has the Request ID only :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/GameRequestDialog.Result/

FB docs says I can access "to": An array of the recipient user IDs for the request that was created:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.3#response

I'm missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the server sends this information, but it's missing in the result payload that the SDK processes. We will add a property for the recipients in an upcoming version of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I have reported this bug using your description of the problem, in case you (or anyone) want to suscribe to it. I hope they fix this soon. Here's the link of the bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1390431761279693

Comment: I did the same, the issue will be fixed in next android sdk release: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1423321764649020

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> id= GameRequestDialog.Result.getRequestRecipients();
String uid = result.getRequestRecipients().get(0);
```

Upgrade your Facebook-Android-Sdk to latest version. 4.5.x +